# How do I remove an array dimension where the elements sum to zero?

Tags: matlab, indexing, matrix

I am assigning a 3D array, which contains some information for a number of different loadcases. Each row in the array defines a particular loadcase (of which there are 3) and I would like to remove the loadcase (i.e. the row) if ALL the elements of the row (in 3D) are equal to zero.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
Array = zeros(3,5) %# Initialise array
Numloadcases = 3;

Array(:,:,1) = [10 10 10 10 10;
                0   0  0  0  0;
                0   0  0  0  0;]; %# Expand to a 3D array 

Array(:,:,2) = [10 10 10 10 10;
                0  0  0  0  0;
                0  0  0  0  0;];

Array(:,:,3) = [10 10 10 10 10;
                0  0  0  0  0;
                0  0  20  0  0;];

Array(:,:,4) = [10 10 10 10 10;
                0  0  0  0  0;
                0  0  20  0  0;];

%# And to remove the second row:

for i = 1:Numloadcases
  if sum(Array(i,:,:)) == 0
    Array(i,:,:) = [];
  end
end
```

At the moment, the for loop I have to remove the rows causes an indexing error, as the size of the array changes in the loop.

Can anyone see a work around for this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to looping, using the function [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) and [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
isAllZero = all(all(Array == 0,3),2);  %# Logical index of rows with all zeroes
Array = Array(~isAllZero,:,:);  %# Keep rows that have non-zero values
%# Or...
Array(isAllZero,:,:) = [];      %# Set rows with all zeroes to the empty matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

the matlab command "any" tells you if there are any nonzero elements.

sum(Array(i,:,:) == 0) will produce true for some mixtures of positive and negative elements (e.g. [1 1 -2]) which is probably not the way to do it.

I would love to be clever and tell you how to do this with no for loops, but the overhead on a for loop here is small and the code is probably clearer if you keep your for loop.  Your mistake is this line:
`Array(i,:,:) = []`
which probably causes Matlab to yell at you about a mismatch in the number of elements

the fix is to keep track of what elements you want to delete, then take care of that at the end of the loop

```
valid = false([1 Numloadcases]); %preallocate
for i = 1:Numloadcases
   valid(i) = any(any(Array(i,:,:)));
end
Array = Array(valid,:,:);
```

If Array is a general ND array you probably don't want to tile up a bunch of any commands, so this alternate formulation will work

```
valid = false([1 Numloacases]);
for i = 1:Numloadcases
   valid(i) = any(reshape(Array(i,:,:), 1, []);
end
Array = Array(valid,:,:);
```

Comment: One problem... `Array(i,:,:)` is actually a 3-D array (1-by-5-by-4 using the example in the question). You therefore have to apply ANY at least twice: `valid(i) = any(any(Array(i,:,:)));`.

Comment: Good catch! I fixed the example & noted you can use reshape as well.

Comment: You should also be able to say "valid(i) = any(Array(i,:))"